# Where I can find a guide in Peru to take me safely to the Jivaro headhunting tribe?

Tags: safety, peru, guides

I'm a psychology major and I would love to barter for a shrunken head if I could still come back with my own.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @JoErNanO it seems that the OP is looking for a guide to take him to the Jivaro headhunting tribe in Peru.  The OP is inserting some comedy into the question suggesting that the tribe might take his own head if he's not with a suitable guide.

Comment: It may be easier and cheaper to buy a head - Google has plenty of hits for "jivaro head for sale".

Comment: Is it legal for ordinary individuals to import human heads from other countries?

Comment: @Jarede Thanks for the clarification. Does the OP want to come home safely with their head intact, or with someone else's head in their hand luggage?

Comment: I'm quite sure that exporting shrunken heads, legally, will require a lot of paperwork. That said, if I'm not mistaken, the Jivaro also reside in Ecuador. I would suggest trying to arrange this from Quito or Cuenca. Or perhaps from Iquitos in Peru.

Comment: @JoErNanO erm, both, clearly... "I would love to barter for a shrunken head if I could still come back with my own"... really not seeing where the reading comprehension problem is here! (p.s. I suspect the "buying a shrunken head" comment is a rather lighthearted request and they're more interested in generally seeing the culture - I'm trusting they're aware that customs in most countries tend not to be too keen on human head imports)

Comment: @user568458, he's not a native English speaker and sometimes various shades of irony are not clear.  In this case the OP's use of a rhetorical zeugma did not carry over well.  Hopefully the OP will recognize this the next time.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what would you like to accomplish, if just go safely to get a shruken head somehow or doing some other research as you mentioned your "psychology major" status. However I would highly recommed you to speak with locals who live near the tribe, they should know how to approach them safely. I may expand my comment into an answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm On a trip to Borneo some years back I asked  a customs guy (Canadian) about the procedures, mostly out of curiosity. Human remains have quite a few regulations and they would have be assured that the original owner of the relic was not a victim of criminal activity. Since that time, trade in parts such as human skeletons from India has become less free.